# Extracting the text and calculation of a div value is getting wrong .

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/5axh3xzs/33/

The price of an Item is 20 . 
When i click on the plus Sign for 3 times , the price of an Item is being shown as 120 rather than 60

please let me know where i am doing wrong

This is my code

http://jsfiddle.net/5axh3xzs/33/

```
$(document).on('click', '.icon-plus', function (e) {
var value = parseInt($(this).closest('div').find('.QtyInput').val());
    $(this).closest('div').find('.QtyInput').val(value+1);

    if(value>0)
    {
    var currentsellprice =  parseInt($(this).closest('.lastItm_Wrap').find('.Itm_right_aside .sellprice').text());
    var currentquantity =parseInt($(this).closest('div').find('.QtyInput').val());
    $(this).closest('.lastItm_Wrap').find('.Itm_right_aside .sellprice').text(currentsellprice*currentquantity);
    }
});
```

Could you please let me know where i am doing wrong .

Comment: You are not holding base price for both item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a way to store the `Item Price`.

I have stored it using `data` attribute in `<h3>` element for `Item2`.

[Updated Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5axh3xzs/35/)

You can do the same for the other items.

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.icon-minus', function (e) {
    var value = parseInt($(this).closest('div').find('.QtyInput').val());
    if(value>=1)
    {
        $(this).closest('div').find('.QtyInput').val(value-1);
    }
});

$(document).on('click', '.icon-plus', function (e) {
    var value = parseInt($(this).closest('div').find('.QtyInput').val());
    $(this).closest('div').find('.QtyInput').val(value+1);

    if(value>0)
    {
        var currentsellprice =  parseInt($(this).parent().prev().data('price')); // get the data "price" of item
        console.log("currentsellprice = " + currentsellprice);
        var currentquantity =parseInt($(this).closest('div').find('.QtyInput').val());
        console.log("currentquantity = " + currentquantity);
        $(this).closest('.lastItm_Wrap').find('.Itm_right_aside .sellprice').text(currentsellprice*currentquantity);
    }
});
```

Comment: this looks more efficient . thanks for pointing it out and a sample solution also .

Answer (score 0):

You're multiplying with the calculated value every time.

The following will fix you problem:

```
$(this).closest('.lastItm_Wrap').find('.Itm_right_aside .sellprice').text((currentsellprice / (currentquantity - 1))*currentquantity);
```

With it you're recalculating the "base sell price".

But this solution isn't very good. Better to store the base-price in it's own div and printing both base-price and the calculated total-price.

Comment: let me check and follow the advice .